# How to close a popover from one viewcontroller by an action in another view controller

Tags: swift, cocoa

I have a popover (in AppDelegate.swift) that present from the status bar when the status bar icon is clicked. A button in this popover (in PopOverViewController) opens another view controller (`NSViewController`). I want the popover to close when this button is clicked. How do you make this happen?

```
 class PopOverViewController: NSViewController {
     @IBAction func showViewController(sender: Any) { 
         AppDelegate().popOver.performClose(sender)
         performSegue(withIdentifier: NSStoryboardSegue.Identifier(rawValue: "seque"), sender: self)
     }  
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Put this on the first line of the action that the button triggers.

```
   self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

if you present using modal,try this one

```
self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
```

or if you present the view using "push" segue

```
self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
```

Comment: @JaredPieniazek you want to dismiss the view right?if yes then this is the code

Comment: I want the popOver to close. If that means the view needs to be dismissed, then yes I want to dismiss the view. If this is the code to dismiss the view than it does not work to close the popOver. I have inserted it into my code and it does not work